# How to get the value of an object in array by key in Typescript

Tags: angular

I have some objects stored in localStorage, I need the value in the objects for some mathematical computations. how do I get them?

```
TCC:"[{"data":197}]"
PCC:"[{"data":30}]"
FCC:"[{"data":159}]"
```

I have successfully retrieved the items from loacalStorage, how do i get the values, i.e 194, 30, 159

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
yourVariable.TCC[0].data
```

should result in 197.

Comment: stored the value in local storage this way. thanks